# stop twitter share button from loading incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jsp, twitter-button

When I enable blur and adblock plus, the twitter button shows up as a hyper-link & worse, it shares the URL of the current page (which is something I dont want to share). Is there anyway I can stop this Tweet button from loading completely when it loads incorrectly ? What can be a good indicator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the twitter button gets wrapped inside an iframe. When tweet button gets rendered as a hypertext link, this iframe does not wrap the div anymore. So I checked if the iframe exists or not and accordingly display/hide the Tweet button.